# Debian,bluetooth не работает

Tags: debian, bluetooth

Когда я использую hcitool dev:

```
sudo hcitool dev
Devices:
```

Ядро:3.16.0-4-amd64

```
lsmod | grep -i blue
bluetooth             374429  6 bnep,btusb
6lowpan_iphc           16588  1 bluetooth
rfkill                 18867  6 cfg80211,acer_wmi,bluetooth
crc16                  12343  2 ext4,bluetooth
```

Вывод команды dmesg:

```
dmesg | grep -i firmware
[    0.166480] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    9.257608] [Firmware Bug]: battery: (dis)charge rate invalid.
[   10.691014] psmouse serio1: elantech: assuming hardware version 3            (with firmware version 0x550f01)
[   11.742351] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI(PEGP) defines _DOD but not _DOS
```

Для bluetooth

```
dmesg | grep -i blue
[   11.300428] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.19
[   11.300445] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   11.300452] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   11.300454] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   11.300464] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   84.877650] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   84.877653] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   84.877658] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

Статус bluetooth service:

```
 bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled)
 Active: active (running) since Вт 2016-03-29 19:11:14 MSK; 1h 21min ago
 Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 1470 (bluetoothd)
 Status: "Running"
 CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
       └─1470 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

 мар 29 19:11:14 debian bluetoothd[1470]: Bluetooth daemon 5.23
 мар 29 19:11:14 debian bluetoothd[1470]: Starting SDP server
 мар 29 19:11:14 debian bluetoothd[1470]: Bluetooth management interface      1...d
 Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

P.S. Если это поможет мой ноутбук - Acer aspire v3-571g